# Magento2 - Custom product attribute in product collection

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection

I've created a new product attribute 'brand'. This attribute is within my default attribute set. Now I'm trying to get all brands from a product collection within a category.

I'm fetching the product collection:

```
$products = $this->_productCollectionFactory
    ->addAttributeToSelect('brand')
    ->addCategoryFilter($activeCategory)
    ->load();
```

But the brand is not displayed? The attribute brand is just a simpel text attribute. How can I fetch all brands from this collection?

Thanks

Comment: did you rebuild the indexes? If you have flat catalog enabled, did you mark the attribute as "used in product listing"?

Comment: Marius, thanks a lot. The option 'Used in product listing' was the fix!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the comments...
when using an attribute in a product collection, if the **flat catalog** is **enabled**, the attribute must be marked as **Used in product listing** in order to be picked up by the collection.

Comment: What if flat catalog isn't enabled?

Comment: @SteveRobbins with flat catalog disabled it should work with out any additional actions.

Comment: Update for 2019: Flat Catalog is considered a performance drag. It should be disabled.

Comment: Hello @Marius, I have disabled Flat Catalog, And in my custom collection I want few attributes like: $collection->addAttributeToSelect(['special_discount', 'special_discount_value', 'special_offer']);. But this is not working. Once I enabled Flat Catalog it's working. How can I achieve this with Flat Catalog disabled value. Can you please suggest.

Comment: with flat catalog disabled it should work as you do it. I have no idea why it doesn't

Comment: perfect answer with explanation!!! +1 made my day!!!